# Slide up layout

Tags: android, slide

I have 2 layouts. I need to show the first layout above the second, and then the user can hide it with a slide up.

[image]

I got a very similar effect with the Umano Library and the slide up panel (https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) , but I couldn't slide the layout on the top (only the bottom layout can be moved).
I hope you understand the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this library, it's very much similar to what you need:
https://github.com/loeschg/android-slide-down-view